# Catch Spring MVC Maxupload Size Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I know its hard to check the file size at the client side(browser) with just pure javascript only.

Now, my question is, Is there a way at the server side to catch an exception such as this?

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size of 2000000 bytes
```

What happens is that, it does not reach my @controller post method and it just throws up the exception that is being catch up by my error.jsp.

What I was thinking is that, is it possible to do this in spring mvc annotated method?

```
@RequestMapping("/uploadFile.htm")
    public String uploadAttachment(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        @RequestParam(required = false, value = "attached-file") MultipartFile file,
        ModelMap model) throws Exception {

        if(checkfilesize(file)){
            //populate model
            //add error if appplicable
            //return same form again
        }
        //return success
    }       
}
```

My problem is, it doesnt reaches upto this point and just throw up a big fat exception.

Although the error.jsp was able to catch it, I would think its much user friendly if I can
alert the user that the file they are about to upload exceeds the limit.

This is Spring MVC 2.5 app by the way.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This exception is thrown in `DispatcherServlet.doDispatch()`, so you should be able to catch this using a `HandlerExceptionResolver` [configured in your context](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#d0e29572).

Comment: thanks.. I made some reading about this and I am using it now.  My problem is, how can I show the same form again populated with the same model and form:error objects.  When I do a forward to the same form again, no data is populated.

Comment: @MarkEstrada If the size of request with all parameters, incl. the file parameter, exceeds the `maxUploadSize`, the request parameters won't be parsed at all. So it doesn't integrate well with validation.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, don't specify `maxUploadSize`, and check in the controller / validator if the size exceeds your limit:

```
if (file.getSize() > 2000000) {
    result.rejectValue("file", "<your.message.key>");
}
```

This checks the size of the file in question, not the file plus all the other request parameters as CommonsMultipartResolver's `maxUploadSize` does.

Comment: Doing this would allow someone to upload an insanely large file and clutter your disk.